# How to profile with DocBook WebHelp and docbkx-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, xslt, profiling, docbook

I created a DocBook manual with an adapted docbkx-maven-plugin in PDF and WebHelp format. The plugin gets the DocBook XSLT templates through a Maven dependency.
For WebHelp I use the DocbkWebHelpMojo with a customization file where the customization file imports the standard webhelp.xsl file

```
<xsl:import href="urn:docbkx:stylesheet/webhelp.xsl"/>
```

Everything works fine.
Now, I want to use profiling. To do so, I think I need to include the xhtml/profile-chunk.xsl template instead of xhtml/chunk.xsl. At the moment, the standard webhelp.xsl file imports xhtml/chunk.xsl and I in turn import webhelp.xsl. Unfortunately, I get errors when I try to import xhtml/profile-chunk.xsl in my customization file which seems due to the fact that all imports are resolved in the context of webhelp. I even copied the whole xhtml folder in my workspace and imported the file directly. This worked but all imports in profile-chunk.xsl failed againg. 
Any ideas?